# How do I add a new queuing discipline to tc in Linux?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

So, I have been trying to implement the Adaptive RED algorithm in the Linux kernel. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I've added sch_newred.ko as a kernel module and defined qdisc_ops for newred in sch_newred.c and compiled and loaded it. Now, when I try to run tc qdisc add dev eth0 root newred, it says, "Unkown qdisc "newred"

Comment: Did you call `register_qdisc` in your module_init function?